# React: How to inject React component into body?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React component that I want to inject into the DOM. This is because my JS will be loaded through a script tag by other website owners, not loaded onto a SPA under my control.

What I want to do is append my `Root` component into the `body` of the webpage.

If I do something like this, then it replaces all the contents of my body, which is not what I want.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class Root extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>heyyyyyyy</div>;
  }
}

if (!module.parent) {
    ReactDOM.render(<Root />, document.querySelector("body")); // <-- wrong
}
```

I want something like `document.querySelector("body").appendChild(<Root />)`. Is this possible?

Comment: I don't understand... why not just add an element where you want your react app to appear?

Comment: I've simplified it for the purpose of SO. the component would be a lot more complex than this in real life

Comment: the concept of appending DOM to some other DOM is the same for all levels of complexity

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you opt for a one-liner :

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Root />,
  document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("DIV"))
)
```

---

### Running Example:

```js
class Root extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>It works!</div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Root />,
  document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("DIV"))
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<body></body>
```

Comment: nice touch on the captials

Answer (score 2):

Create the root element and append it to the DOM yourself

```js
const rootEl = document.createElement('div')

document.body.appendChild(rootEl)


class Root extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return <div>heyyyyyyy</div>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Root />,
  rootEl
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div>don't replace me</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I put my extended and complex answer cause it may help if you need to import *one/multiple react components* without npm in server side render:

You may go without NPM/Webpack but you gotta use babel:
In my case it is server side rendering, that's why i cannot use npm

First: import all dependencies and put your main module like this to html :

```
    <script type="module" src="/jsx/mainPage.js"></script>
    //specify js, not jsx because babel compiles jsx files to js

    <script>
      new mainPage({
        containerID: "${parentID}"
      })
    </script>

<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
//since babel-watched is used, you dont need babel cdn lib anymore
```

Second: write your jsx in the next way

```
//my MainPage.jsx

{ ChildPageComponent } from './childPage.js';

window.MainPage = function(props) {
  ReactDOM.render(<MainPageComponent constainerID={props.containerID}/>, 
  document.getElementById(props.containerID));

}

class MainPageComponent extends React.Component { 
  render() {
    return <ChildPageComponent/>
  }
... }
```

my child page.jsx

```
export class ChildPageComponent extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return(<div>helloword</div>)
  }
}
```

But the most helpful is ***Babel watcher***. This bash script helps to install and run babel-watcher. You gotta specify your pathes for source and compiled project files

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! -d "node_modules" ]; then
    npm init -y
    npm install babel-cli@6 babel-preset-react-app@3
fi

SOURCES=~/Documents/yourpath/project/jsx
OUT=~/Documents/yourpath/project/jsx

npx babel --watch $SOURCES --out-dir $OUT --presets react-app/prod
```

Sure it help you because i was looking for this way for a long